# How can I limit digit input to 10 on my regex pattern for mobile number?

Tags: regex

I have a regex pattern for extracting mobile numbers i.e.:

```
\b[(+]*[0-9]+[()+. -]*\b
```

But this also takes in input like 1234 which I don't want. I am a total newbie and have no idea all I know is limit is being restricted by adding `\d{10}`, but I am not able to append this into my pattern.

Comment: Provide all acceptable (in your use case) phone number formats.

Comment: Without any details, I can only suggest something very clumsy, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/YA1MqX/1).

Comment: The `{n}` (exact count), `{n,}` (minimum count), `{,m}` (maximum count) and `{n,m}` (at least n, at most m) constructs are not restricted to the `\d` pattern. Give us some examples of acceptable and non-acceptable matches, and then we will be able to help more.

Comment: acceptable patterns- +91-9883443344
9883443344
09883443344
919883443344
0919883443344
+919883443344
+91-9883443344
0091-9883443344
+91 -9883443344
+91- 9883443344
+91 - 9883443344
0091 - 9883443344
7856128945
9998564723
022-24130000
080 25478965
0416-2565478
08172-268032
04512-895612
02162-240000
+91 9883443344
022-24141414  unacceptable patterns - 12365478964123 , 000021478596641 , 123 , 12 , 321456